# Join if temporary table exists

Tags: mysql

Briefly,

How I create my temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp_table SELECT * FROM db1;
```

then,

```
# if tmp_table does exist
SELECT db2.*, _tmp_table.* FROM 'db2' LEFT OUTER JOIN _tmp_table ON _tmp_table.key = db2.id;
# if tmp_table does NOT exist
SELECT db2.* FROM db2;
```

How can I make only one query to deal with my temporary table existing or not?

Env: `Mysql 5.5.15`.

Comment: Why not create the temp table every time. If you don't put anything in it, the left join will still return all rows of `db2.*`.

Comment: @Barmar would not it have a bad impact on performance ?

Comment: I don't think so -- it shouldn't take much effort for it to tell that it's joining with an empty table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it in one statement.

You need an assurance that the table you are joining existed or else you will be getting an exception. I rather create a stored procedure for that which checks for table existence.

Comment: I could not find a way to check for table existence when the table is temporary.